# Recurring Daily Countdown

Tags: javascript, html

I need a recurring countdown clock to count down to the same time. I found this code online, tried to modify it, but I was not able to add 24 hours to the hours once the timer hit 0, so it would loop. This code will be used at the header of all the pages on a Shopify site.

```js
// The data/time we want to countdown to
var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 23, 2020 14:27:52").getTime();

// Run myfunc every second
var myfunc = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var timeleft = countDownDate - now;

  // Calculating the days, hours, minutes and seconds left
  var days = Math.floor(timeleft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Result is output to the specific element
  document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days + "d "
  document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours + "h "
  document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = minutes + "m "
  document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = seconds + "s "

  // Display the message when countdown is over
  if (timeleft < 0) {
    clearInterval(myfunc);
    document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("end").innerHTML = "TIME UP!!";

    var hours = +24
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="days"></p>
<p id="hours"></p>
<p id="mins"></p>
<p id="secs"></p>
<h2 id="end"></h2>
```

Comment: Hey and welcome. Please describe what is working and what not. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the hour, minute, and second to a new Date object with today's date and check if it's in the past. If it is, just add an extra day to it.

```js
function countdown() {
  const now = new Date();
  const hour = 14;
  const minute = 30;
  const second = 0;

  let maxTime = new Date(
    now.getFullYear(),
    now.getMonth(),
    now.getDate(),
    hour,
    minute,
    second,
  );

  if (now > maxTime) {
    maxTime = new Date(
      now.getFullYear(),
      now.getMonth(),
      now.getDate() + 1,
      hour,
      minute,
      second,
    );
  }

  const countDownDate = maxTime.getTime();
  const timeleft = countDownDate - new Date().getTime();
  const days = Math.floor(timeleft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hours = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const minutes = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const seconds = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = `${days}d `;
  document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = `${hours}h `;
  document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML = `${minutes}m `;
  document.getElementById('secs').innerHTML = `${seconds}s `;
}

const intervalId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

```html
<p>
  <span id="days"></span>
  <span id="hours"></span>
  <span id="mins"></span>
  <span id="secs"></span>
</p>
```